# Как получить HINSTANCE модуля в котором находится код?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Как в MS Visual C++ получить `HINSTANCE` модуля (exe или dll) в котором находится текущая функция?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я согласен, что вариант с `__ImageBase` можно использовать в определенных случаях, но хотел упомянуть о двух других стандартных методах.

Чаще всего необходимо получить `HINSTANCE` основной программы (EXE). Для этого проще всего использовать [GetModuleHandle(NULL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx).

Другая типичная ситуация, что мы написали DLL с callback функцией и ее кто-то вызывает. В этом случае у нас обычно есть параменры переданные вазывающим нас модулем. С помощью `GetModuleHandleEx` с параметром `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` можно получит `HMODULE` по адесу переменной, а `HINSTANCE` DLL это и есть `HMODULE`.

Есть конечно много других способов. Но решающим является в каком контексте мы находимся.

Мне лично, в свое время, дало многое для общего поминания программка которую я включил в [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010909/315935). Она показывает, что огромное виртуальное пространства процесса зазбито на блоки и каждый блок принадлежит своему модулю. Имея начала модуля можно поличить о нем всю информацию. Я полагаю, что `GetModuleHandleEx` работает примерн так.

Comment: С одной стороны Вы правы, `GetModuleHandle/Ex` - стандартные методы, и их использование более оправдано, но если Вы правы насчет "GetModuleHandleEx работает примерн так", то Ваше предложение хуже @Abyx, т.к. Вы предлагаете, по сути обойти всю виртуальную память и посканировать начало каждого выделенного блока, вместо того, чтобы просто передать в нужный контекст необходимый там `HINSTANCE`, который обычно передается в `DllMain`. С точки зрения оптимизации, я выберу вариант @Abyx, как более приемлемый.

Comment: @mega: Я прежде всего хотел дополнить, что **`GetModuleHandle(NULL)` и `GetModuleHandleEx` могуть быть использованы в большинстве сценариев**. Пример с виртуальную память имеет лишь важный аспект понимания. Я писал в том старом ответе, что цикл занимал порядка 200 шагов и работал моментально. Просто много лет назад я много "баловался" анализируя память или структуру Exe или Dll как на диске так и в памяти. Но, по сути все это уже известно. Я упомянул об этом лишь стараясь пояснит работу `GetModuleHandleEx`. Возможно, это только запутало.

Comment: Я не спорю насчет "могуть быть использованы в большинстве сценариев", поэтому и написал, что тут Вы правы. Но сейчас век `x64` и больших объемов данных (которым, как правило нужно много памяти). Не думаю, что Вы пишете серьезно об оценке в `200` шагов, т.к. это зависит от поведения самого приложения: с чем оно работает, что делает. Вот придет кому-нить в голову мысль выделять млн страничных блоков, а это всего `4гига`. И ваши 200 шагов вырастут как минимум на млн. Т.е. я предостерегаю от использования такого метода "неподумамши о таких последствиях".

Comment: @mega: Во-первых, я забыл упомянуть, что HINSTANCE и HMODULE - это ни что иное, как *виртуальный одрес начала PE-заголовка соответствующего модуля (EXE DLL)*. Наверное, для x64 можно поступить по-другому. Но относительно поведения самого приложения вы заблуждаетель. Обычно регервируется дольшой блок  виртуальной памяти, который совершенно не связан с физической памятью, а затем этот блок используется С++ для выделения маленьких блоков. *При этом у нас остается тот же один виртуальный блок*. Просто обычто на нужно защищать блок на исполнение или модификащию и количество виртуальных блоков мало.

Comment: Насчет "обычно регервируется дольшой блок виртуальной памяти" я знаю. Я Вам привел пример **не из "обычной практики"**. Ни что не мешает нам взять заботы по управлению памяти в свои руки (а, например, при работе в `x86` через `AWE`, Вам просто придется это сделать). Пример как раз из этой серии. Но в любом случае, Вы полагаетесь на какое-то ограниченное число виртуальных блоков памяти в архитектуре, которая подразумевает ее наращивание, а это идеологически неверно.

Comment: @mega: Извините, но я не уверен, что мы говорим об одном и том же. Я написал кароткий комментарий к ответу Abyx' добавив лишь о друкой позможности `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` и `GetModuleHandleEx` с `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS`. Он меня попросил написать лучше свой ответ вместо комментария, Что я и сделал. Так как при загрузке exe и dll всегда устанавливаются атрибуты виртуальной памяти (см. [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx), то только поэтому использается *медленная* `VirtualAllocEx`. Я просто не понимаю смасла паследующей дискусии.

Comment: Я просто указал на **разницу в производительности** обоих методов, чтобы люди, которые будут использовать Ваш ответ, ее учитывали.

Comment: @mega: я вообще не предложил никакого "своего метода". Я лишь в конце упомянул, для общего поминания, что огромное виртуальное пространства процесса разбито на блоки и каждый блок принадлежит своему модулю. Обычно количество блоков чрезвычайно мало 200-1000 и `HINSTANCE` и `HMODULE` совпадают а адресами начала виртуальных блоков. `EnumProcessModules`, например, позволяет просмотреть все модули. Но все это уходит в сторону от заданного вопроса, мой ответ на который: **использование `GetModuleHandleEx` с `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` или `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`** и ничего более.

Comment: Да, так можно долго бодаться. Впрочем, свой выбор я уже сделал, и, думаю, хорошо объяснил, почему.

Comment: @mega: Меня просто поражает разница в стиле дискуссий на ru.stackoverflow.com от stackoverflow.com. Я несколько дней назад случайно обнаружил существование ru.stackoverflow.com, но после первых же своих комментариев я отвечал лишь на вопросы других комментаторов. Другие комментаторы пытались мне что-то доказать, а исходный вопрос уже мала кого интересовал. Меня лишь интересует помочь конкретному человеку задавшему вопрос, даже если он абсолютный новичек, и ничего больше. Репутация меня не интересует вообще и общие дисскуссии тоже.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34414/discussion-between-mega-and-oleg).

Answer (score 2):

`HINSTANCE` - это адрес, по которому модуль размещен в памяти.

Visual C++, а точнее линкер `link.exe` объявляет специальный символ для заголовка исполняемого файла:

```
extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
```

Т.к. заголовок файла находится в начале файла, то адрес заголовка - это адрес модуля, т.е. `HMODULE` или `HINSTANCE`. Таким образом можно написать

```
const HINSTANCE current_module = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase;
```

По скольку `__ImageBase` определяет линкер (`link.exe`), то это решение можно использовать с любым компилятором, если он компилирует файлы в формат  совместимый с link.exe (т.е. формат MS COFF).

Comment: I want to add that one can use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` to get `HINSTANCE` of the EXE and to use `GetModuleHandleEx` with `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` to get `HMODULE` of DLL (the `HINSTANCE` of a DLL is the same as the `HMODULE` of the DLL), because one have typically address inside of the DLL.

Comment: @Oleg - у нас тут все как-бы по-русски. Даже в названии написано - SO на русском!

Comment: @gbg: Извините, отвлекся. Сейчас напишу по-русски.